# iPhone DRM implementation for audio and video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drm, copy-protection

I've done a lot of googling, to no avail,
I'm interested in knowing what my native or third party options are for implementing DRM to protect audio (say in a spotify like scenario) and video.(for VOD applications)
 I've seen mention of widevine but all the content seems to be at least 18 months to 2 years old.
What options do i have for implementing DRM on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are PlayReady- or Widevine DRM-based solutions for iOS, such as [this one](https://www.insidesecure.com/Markets-solutions/Content-Protection-and-Entertainment/DRM-Agent-for-Downloadable-Deployment) by Inside Secure. They supply an SDK to integrate DRM audio/video protection in your apps (disclaimer: I work there).

Comment: Does this solution provides or will provide DRM solution for other kind of files such as pdf or epub? Thanks for your time